# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/user_image_name.jpg open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) Crash Application

Tags: android

How can i handle filenotfoundexception. My application crash on some devices but works well on others. is there a try catch to handle file not found exeption or how can i handle this error.

```
   03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): error: /storage/emulated/0/user_image_name.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/user_image_name.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at name.secondname.app.utils.HttpRequest.doFileUpload(HttpRequest.java:2949)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at name.secondname.app.moncompte.Editer$uploadImageLoadingTask.doInBackground(Editer.java:1099)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at name.secondname.app.moncompte.Editer$uploadImageLoadingTask.doInBackground(Editer.java:1)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
    03-31 12:25:49.477: E/MediaPlayer(28356): ... 10 more
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at name.secondname.app.utils.HttpRequest.doFileUpload(HttpRequest.java:3006)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at name.secondname.app.moncompte.Editer$uploadImageLoadingTask.doInBackground(Editer.java:1099)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at name.secondname.app.moncompte.Editer$uploadImageLoadingTask.doInBackground(Editer.java:1)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    03-31 12:25:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(28356): ... 4 more
```

Comment: Are you **assuming** what the file path will be, or are you *discovering* it at runtime using the proper APIs?  Regardless, your program must allow for the fact that the file (or even the entire External Storage mount) might not exist.  So first fix any mistakes such as assuming what the path will be on a given device, or program logic errors that cause you to think the file should be there when it has not yet been created.  But after that, you should probably handle the Exception in a try/catch block, as the file/filesystem could still vanish on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, put a try-catch block around the file open logic and handle the exception when you catch the exception.

```
try {
    // File related operations
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle the exception here
}
```